# Unexpected result in union (C++)

Tags: c++, unions

I study in high school and I was making a program just to understand how a union works but the program is giving me unexpected results.

This was the program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union c{
    int l;
    int b;
    int h;
    int vol;
};

int main() {
    c box;
    box.l=1;
    box.b=2;
    box.h=3;

    box.vol = box.l*box.b*box.h;

    cout<<"\n Volume :-  "<<box.vol;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output was as follows :

```
 Volume :-  27
```

I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I think you should go over how unions work once more.

Comment: why? If there is any error, please tell me

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. You cannot set *all* the members of an union and expect they retain their values. Use a struct for this. Members of an union are (let me say) exclusive, you use either the first one **or** the second one and so on. It would be an UB but for the fact that it gives you a predictable result being them all `int`. Anyway, as I said, your expectation is wrong, not the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... btw is it the reason that i am getting powers of the last variable (ie. h)

Answer (score 2):

You are having this issue because you are treating a `union` as though it were a `struct`.

A Union allocates a memory space that can contain *any* of the elements but not *all* of them.  In the way that you have written it, there are three names that effectively point to the same address.  This means that, based upon the assignments, you end up putting a 3 into the allocated space.

In other words, the way that you have written this, you have simply created four ways of referencing the same data.

An example of a way to use a union would be to describe two or more alternate structures.  For example:

```
union Shape {
  struct triangle {
    int base;
    int height;
  }
  struct rectangle {
    int length;
    int width;
  }
}
```

You are now able to use a single data type to handle either case.

Comment: So can you provide me a program with union that does the same same work as a structure would have done here?

Comment: And actually i use structure in most cases ... i am not used to unions :P

Comment: You wouldn't use a union for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did add an example, but it's still not a great example.  A better case might be in a network stack, allowing you to define alternative protocol header definitions that can be selected at access time rather than compile time.

Comment: @Fullatron Just as a head-up: in C++17 there will be a `std::variant` type, which is a type-safe union. You should use it instead of raw unions. At least it will transform UB into errors.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I think registers are a great example of unions, al, ah and ax if you want to add that as an example.